# What is use of Proxy in frontend part

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

What is use of Proxy `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` in `Package.json`  in frontend part
when Backend (API Part) is starting in 5000 Port ?

Please Explain how Proxy work in package.json when calling rest API.
and also explain how writing proxy provide to directly with the API

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/),

> People often serve the front-end React app from the same host and port as their backend implementation.
>
> ....
>
> To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`.

So the `proxy` field in `package.json` sets up a proxy server for the frontend API requests, allowing communication with the backend on a different port while bypassing same-origin policy restrictions.